# PHP Searching from type and name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry for the bad title, but I don't know a better alternative.

Currently I'm creating a search engine to get product detail. I have 2 search types, 1st I'm searching by using product type, and another one is by using product name.

Here is the search code:

```
<?php
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

$x = "";
$construct = "";  

foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each) {
    $x++;
    if ($x==1)
        $construct .="product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    else
        $construct .="AND product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}
?>
```

and this is the data fetch code.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM produk2 WHERE $construct" );
if ($results) {

    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while ($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<div class="product">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
        echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/'.$obj-  >product_img_name.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-info">';
        echo 'Price '.$currency.$obj->price.' | ';
        echo 'Qty <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />';
        echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

How can I change the data search from `product_type` to `product_name` and vice versa, based on what I'm getting from user input?

I can't really explain it better, because of my poor English.

Comment: your constructs' concatenates are missing spaces for one thing. You should be getting syntax errors but you're probably not checking for them. This for instance `.="AND` should read as `.=" AND`

Comment: on top of the header i get the data from another page using $search = $_GET ['search_value'];

Comment: fred, the construct works perfectly well, for product_type, but i don't know how to change it between product type and name

Comment: Use the Mapper below. If you're trying to basically toggle your search fields, that's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it a `OR` condition rather like below. That way, whatever uset types will be applied against both column and since it's a `OR` condition, it will return true if either matches.

```
where product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'
or product_name LIKE '%$search_each%';
```

Modify your below code segment

```
if ($x==1)
    $construct .="product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
    $construct .="AND product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

To be

```
$construct .="product_type LIKE '%$search_each%' OR product_name LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You say poor english, so please correct me if I'm misunderstanding the issue: You want to use a single method to search one of two fields depending on the search type?

If so: this is a design pattern I use quite frequently. It's basically a mapper class that behaves something like a factory. I use a class here, because I usually do far more than this with it (have it pick out different tables and all sorts of things). You can probably rewrite it for procedural if all you need to do is map two fields.

```
<?php
$search_exploded = explode(" ", $search);

$x = "";
$construct = "";

$mapper = new Mapper();

foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each) {
  $x++;

  // pass in what you want to map. in this example, it will take either prodtype or prodname, and return the field that you want
  $tablename = $mapper->getMap();
  if ($x == 1)
    $construct .= "$tablename LIKE '%$search_each%'";
  else
    $construct .= "AND $tablename LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

class Mapper
{
  public $map = array(
      'prodtype' => 'product_type',
      'prodname' => 'product_name'
  );

  public function getMap($forsearch)
  {
    return $this->map[$forsearch];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to .

```
foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each) {
    $x++;
    if ($x==1)
        $construct .="product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    else
        $construct .="OR product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}
?>
```

In this case whatever input the user give, it will get the data.